# How can I sure my background colour fills whole webpage background?

Tags: css

I was wondering how I can ensure that section 1 and two's background colour fills the whole of the webpage like in this [example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usRz6.jpg) As you can see on my site, the background colour on covers half of the webpage I want the background colour for section one and two to full the whole background of that section.

I have tried using the CSS. However, this doesn't work.

```
.one {
  background-color:#c00;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**SITE CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
} 

.one {
  background-color:#c00;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.two {
  background: #563D7C;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="container-fluid">
         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
         </div>
         <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="#">Home</a>
             </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                 </li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                 </li>

                 <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                 </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
             </li>
             <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
         <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
       </div>
       <!-- /.container-fluid -->
     </nav>
     <div id="sections">
            <div class="section one">
              <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
                <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
              </div>



            <a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>



            </div>
            <div class="section two"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#sections').fullpage();
            });
        </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In its current form, your question shows ***zero*** research effort. You are showing us what you have in bulk and demand a feature. With all due respect, we're here to help you, not to serve you. Please show some will to learn. Share what you've read and what you've tried and didn't work. I guarantee it will improve your chances of getting an answer you'll find helpful. Besides, your request is quite basic. It's not that people don't know how to help you, it's more that your question, in its current form, gives no incentive to do so. Consider creating a [mcve] (`<>` button).

Comment: Ok thanks, I have updated the post.

Comment: It's far from `mcve` (you're supposed to put each part in its panel and make sure it works). I appreciate the effort and that's what I wanted to see. Some good will. I'm already writing an answer and trying to make it helpful for you. There's one thing I have to ask. How are the sections supposed to split the screen? In half horizontally, vertically, or should each be a full-screen size?

Comment: I want each section to be a full-screen size. Here is an [example.](http://imgur.com/a/qmfhe) the orange colour represents section one. Just for reference in case your wondering I'm going to use an arrow to link each section together. `<a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It looks like you are loading `jQuery` twice. Once in the header (in the Bootstrap links) and once in the footer, for `fullpage.js`. Since you already loaded it once, you don't need it the second time.
2. Wrapping all your content in a `.container` will add a `15px` left and right padding to your content, unless you don't place everything in it inside `.row` (which compensates), as in all the Bootstrap examples.

Make sure your markup is correct and validates. I also added a small `CSS`:

```
#sections .section {
  padding-top: 10vh;
}
```

...to compensate for the height of the navbar.
However, please note ***it is not recommended to have the navbar in scalable units(`vh`)***. You should just stick to Bootstrap's defaults (`50px`). The problem with having a fixed navigation of `10vh` is it will eat up too much real estate on mobile devices in portrait mode while not being tall enough for touch events in landscape mode. So, IMHO, you should change both the top padding of the `.section`s and the navbar height back to `~50px` (min `42px`). The important part is you should ***use `px` instead of `vh` for navbar height***.

Here it is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sections').fullpage();
});
```

```css
.body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
} 

.one {
  background-color:#c00;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.two {
  background: #563D7C;
}
#sections .section {
  padding-top: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div id="sections">
    <div class="section one">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
            <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="section two"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Additional note:**

`fullpage.js` takes care of the fullpage thing for you. However, I happen to believe this is something `CSS` is capable of doing without any `js`, using, in principle:

```
.section {
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

...and probably `flexbox` to center align or distribute children nicely.

But, by using `fullpage.js`, you don't need to do it via `CSS`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help and thanks for reformatting my code I really do appreciate it. I will now do some research on some of the things you said and thanks for going above and beyond in the answer to make it clear. Lastly, I'll take into account your advice when posting questions. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll make a small addition in a few minutes you're going to need in order for your fixed navbar not to cover section content anymore.

Comment: Quick question, you said how it was recommended to do this ` #sections .section {
  padding-top: 10vh;
}` is there any other proper way of doing this then? In addition, what is this called so I can make my own inquiries on this as well?

Comment: @AJKCJDC, I made it `10vh` because you made the navigation height `10vh`. The proper way to do it is to not alter the default height of navigation from Bootstrap (which is `50px`) and match the top padding of sections to it. The minimal height of buttons, so they are friendly on touch devices too, according to multiple sources/studies is around `42px`. With the current `10vh`, it's going to eat up too much real estate on phones, in portrait mode, while being way too short in portrait mode.

Comment: The use of `vh` is not consistent in many devices or browsers. Also a fixed height is required to deal with some fullPage.js options such as `scrollOverflow:true` or even `verticalCentered:true` in others.